# Creating a central directory where any userform can access the variables (explained in detail in description)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

The problem I encountered in this program is that I realized that the variables I have listed below (I'm creating a game) will be needed across many of the userforms I'm going to add into the project. To solve this, I have decided to create a "central directory", where the program can get the data it needs to function.

It is important to note I'm still learning VB, so there might be chance I might not understand what you are trying to express.

So far, here is my code.

```
Public Shared strength As Integer = 0
Public Shared constitution As Integer = 0
Public Shared dexterity As Integer = 0
Public Shared intelligence As Integer = 0
Public Shared wisdom As Integer = 0
Public Shared charisma As Integer = 0
Public Shared perception As Integer = 0
Public Shared luck As Integer = 0
```

Is there a central directory I can create to make it happen? Or do you have other solutions? Feel free to ask questions for clarification.

Comment: You're just talking about global variables.  The usual way to create a global variable in VB.NET is to add a module to your project and then declare a public variable there.  That variable is now accessible anywhere in your project.

Comment: thanks. I'm going to try that as soon as Visual Studio is finished updating.

Comment: One possible problem with global variables is that there is only one copy of them.  Your variables seem like properties that a character in a game might have.  Will you have more than one character?  And will they all have the same strength, constitution, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class altogether and keep it in a different folder .

```
Public Class
Public Shared strength As Integer = 0
Public Shared constitution As Integer = 0
Public Shared dexterity As Integer = 0
Public Shared intelligence As Integer = 0
Public Shared wisdom As Integer = 0
Public Shared charisma As Integer = 0
Public Shared perception As Integer = 0
Public Shared luck As Integer = 0
End class
```

And use this object to get the shared values across forms on form load.